# Quando usar criptografia ao Desenvolver para Dispositivos móveis?

Tags: android, criptografia

Estou estudando e montando projetos para dispositivos móveis, e sempre me deparo com dezenas de transmissao de dados, alguns importante outros não

1)gostaria de saber se é conveniente criptografar todos os dados que salvo no sqlite

2) In codigo,  a hora que carrego a função Consigo criptografar ali, ou só na hora que seto os valores, faria a conversão e mandaria para o banco?

se Possivel gostaria de algumas dicas de como fazer, de uma maneira eficiente
e se devo mesmo fazer.

ex:   tenho a seguinte função para inserir usuarios no banco
eu criptografo na hora de converter e faço a inserção?
e se eu quizer exibir os dados do banco em uma lista?
eu descriptografo da mesma forma, digo na mesma situação que na inserção?

```
 public void Cadastrar(){
 final EditText etid = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etid);
        final EditText etnome = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etnome);
        final EditText etusuario = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etusuario);
        final EditText etsenha = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etsenha);
        final EditText etemail = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.etemail);

 nome = etnome.getText().toString();
                email = etemail.getText().toString();
                usuarios = etusuario.getText().toString();
                senha = etsenha.getText().toString();
                id_tipo = etid.getText().toString();
                u = new Usuarios_Model();

                u.setNome(nome);
                u.setEmail(email);
                u.setSenha(senha);
                u.setUsuario(usuarios);
                u.setTipo_usuario(tipo);
                u.setId(Integer.parseInt(id_tipo));
                List<Usuarios_Model> ls = new ArrayList<>();

                ls.add(u);

                new DAO_usuario().Insert(ls);
```

}

**Nota:**  estou estudando o PBKDF2, ja consegui montar exemplos simples, porém tenho um projeto que gostaria de colocar criptografia nele

Comment: Pesquise sobre [SQLCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/sqlcipher/)

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski eu tenho um metodo implementado em Rijndael.

entretando ouvi falar que o  PBKDF2 tinha um bom desempenho então estava pensando em uma forma de utiliza-lo. gostaria de esclarecer essas duvidas, por isso o  pedido final de 

" utilizar de maneira eficiente"

em alguns aplicativos poderia utilizar, ja que o trafego seria diferente do que o Rijndael.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Você terá que avaliar cada caso, pois se você decidir criptografar tudo, você estará agregando um tempo maior de processamento que poderá deixar seu app mais lento. Na minha opinião informações como senhas, usuário, número do cartão de crédito etc.. devem sempre serem criptografadas, o resto vai depender da criticidade da informação.

2 - Faz uma rotina que criptografa/descriptografa as informações na leitura do banco.

Comment: carina, só nao marco como resposta pois ainda continuo com duvidas,
"se Possivel gostaria de algumas dicas de como fazer, de uma maneira eficiente e se devo mesmo fazer."